# Site url is not generated correctly when using environment variables

Tags: craft3, localization, url, env

I'm working on a multi-site setup (for a localized website). In my `.env` file, I have defined a `SITE_BASE_URL` variable. Then, in the control panel, I set up each site's base url with that environment variable (e.g. `http://$SITE_BASE_URL/en`, `http://$SITE_BASE_URL/nl`, etc. for each language).

However, when I need to generate urls in my Twig templates, this environment variable doesn't seem to get parsed; I get generated html that looks like this `<a href="http://$SITE_BASE_URL/en/services">...</a>`.

Example from a twig template:

```
{% set pages = [
    craft.entries.section("services").one(),
    craft.entries.section("products").one(),
] %}

{% for page in pages %}
<a href="{{ page.url }}">{{page.title}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

This gives me URLs like `http://$SITE_BASE_URL/en/services`, `http://$SITE_BASE_URL/en/products`, etc.

This setup was working fine for me when using the `@web` alias in the CP. Why doesn't it work with the env variable? The only reason I switched to env variables is that it is not recommended to use the `@web` alias due to cache poisoning.

I've already looked at https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/3719 and [baseUrl outputs environment variable](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/29490/baseurl-outputs-environment-variable)

Neither have solved my issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cache poisoning would only happen if you don't *hard-set* your `@web` alias manually and it is auto-determined.

Set it in your `config/general.php` with:

```php
'aliases' => [
    'web' => getenv('SITE_BASE_URL'),
],
```

Then you'll be able to revert to using it in your Control Panel.

In terms of why this happened; you can't *add* to an environment variable the way you can with an alias so `http://$SITE_BASE_URL/en` will become a string and the variable aspect of it will disappear.

When you define `$SITE_BASE_URL`, it can only be used *as is* in the CP so if you wanted to use variables for you site, you would need to define one for each site/language.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick! I'd still like to know what the issue is with using the env variable, though...

Comment: @idix - added above

Comment: Okay, that makes it clear to me, thanks. Is this explained somewhere in the docs? Up until now, I haven't seen it mentioned I think (at least not in the clear way you just explained it).

Comment: [The first sentence here](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/#using-aliases-in-control-panel-settings) touches on it but it's not covered in details.